# Trying to show all unique SMS senders in Android

Tags: android, group-by, sms, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to write my first android app, and I need to display all the unique SMS senders in one screen. Like an inbox.

But I'm unable to use group by or distinct in the content resolver query, and all sql-injection-like workarounds on stackoverflow don't seem to be working.

Is there an obvious method I'm missing out? Because this seems to be a pretty basic thing. I'm querying the SMS db so can't use rawquery either (a method other similar posters seem to have used).

Some help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Check Out This : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268038/android-async-task-error

Answer (score 0):

just find out URLS for SMS. then using content resolver get the data from that URL.

Comment: But I am already using the URI for SMS, (content://sms/inbox), I need to get a group by clause into the contentresolver.query statement for it. Or do you mean the SMS inbox has multiple URIs?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on how I did it:

```
// getting sender list from messages into spinner View
    Spinner phoneListView = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.phone_list);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");     
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{"Distinct address"}, null, null, null);
    List <String> list;
    list= new ArrayList<String>();
    list.clear();
    int msgCount=c.getCount();
    if(c.moveToFirst()) {
        for(int ii=0; ii < msgCount; ii++) {
            list.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString());
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    phoneListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(BankActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list));
```